# Clients/IP and Device Monitor

Tags: c, linux, sockets, device

Say I want to have a server that can accept socket connection and also can monitor devices which are plugged in the server.

There will be two things the server can do.

**1. Accept/Monitor Client connections via TCP/IP(recv and send from them);**

**2. Monitor Devices(recv and send from the devices);**

From number 1 i plan to use linux sockets to accept client connections.

From number 2 i plan to use libudev.h library to monitor devices. which have a tutorial on signal11..

I have already code linux sockets and libudev.h.. but they're separate user space app. I need to merge them as one.. How am i supposed to do this?.

Or any suggestions how can i do this? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to multiplex your I/O?

If that's all you're asking then you have a selection of options. The traditional UNIX way would be to use select or poll. - http://www.linux-mag.com/id/331/

Or you could go for spawning threads for each of the connections that need I/O done on them. This is naturally the easiest option, but is fraught with risk in terms of maintaining data integrity between the two threads, locking and race conditions make a solid implementation trickier (I think) than poll.

You could of course still keep them as separate processes and then use some method of IPC (Shared memory, message queues etc.) to a third process to unify the functionality of the two. This is perhaps a little heavier than the threaded option but with better separation between the two processes, making it more resilient at the cost of (potentially) more work.

Can you clarify your question a little more?!

Comment: Yes you got my point.. It's like a broker server that monitor devices this devices use physical port to connect and devices that are connected in a network which uses ip to connect to the server. Which the broker server monitors. Technically it relay messages to the devices.

Comment: Yes.. so it's okay to merge my program then?

Comment: I would say it's going to be a necessity at some time. Depending on what you're trying to achieve though the different approaches all have benefits and drawbacks. Most applications of a decent size spend their time alternating between all the different ins and outs of their problem domain.